# Cors error strict-origin-when-cross-origin simple nodeJS-reactJS project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to upload image to Cloundinary, but an error occurred with status code 500 relating to cors though i had set the server to allow all origin.

The error message is:

```
POST http://localhost:5000/my-route-upload 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

here is my POST function :

```
const cloudinaryUpload = (fileToUpload) => {
    return axios.post(API_URL + '/cloudinary-upload', fileToUpload)
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        console.log("cannot post")
    }); }
```

In server side, I had added the following block in App.JS

```
const cors = require('cors'); 
var app = express();
app.use(cors({
  origin: "*",
  })
);
```

Those codes did execute, i tried modify the origin to the specific one like http://127.0.0.1:3001 (my client port is 3000). Then it came out another error message

Back to the first error, in tab Network/Headers :

```
Request URL: http://localhost:5000/cloudinary-upload
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Host: localhost:5000
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

I don't know why it didn't work. I use create-react-app for client and Express generator for server

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should add the content-type header to your Axios request. Like this.

```
const res = await axios.post('url', data, {
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  }
});
```

Comment: it still doesn't work

`const cloudinaryUpload = (fileToUpload) => {
    return axios.post(API_URL + '/cloudinary-upload', fileToUpload, {headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      }})
    .then(res => res.data)
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        console.log("cannot post")
    });
}`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Setup a proxy for your server from your client

Proxy can be a simple
`"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` in your package.json, where all unknown requests will be proxied to localhost:5000
Essentially you need to call the api from client as `/my-route-upload` instead of `http://localhost:5000/my-route-upload`.

But preferred method would be to add a file called `src/setupProxy.js` 
and
`$ npm install http-proxy-middleware --save`
add this to the file

````
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:5000',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};```

Also look at enabling cors in express
https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html
````

Answer (score 1):

```
const cors = require('cors'); 
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

try this

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

This middleware helps to avoid cross-platform error

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  next();
});
```

Set this header middleware on your root file above your all routes in the express app, Update this code block with your server cors block in AppJS

Comment: With this middleware?

Comment: I had a mistake in validation with Cloudanry. But the error appeared like it came from cors